# Reactive object in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have an array of objects (array 1), that can be toggled to another array (array 2). When added the user has the option to type in a text field for each option. The toggling works fine and is reactive on the initial creation. But if I have data that already exists in array 2, the item is no longer reactive.

I have made a quick jsfiddle to demonstrate: Event 1 and 3 are reactive, but event 2 no longer is as it already exists in the newEvents array. Is there anyway to get this connected to the original event?

```js
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        events: [
          { id: 1, text: "Event 1"},
          { id: 2, text: "Event 2"},
          { id: 3, text: "Event 3"}
        ],
        savedEvents: [
         { id: 2, text: "Event 2", notes: 'Event Notes'}
        ]
      },
      methods: {
       toggleEvent: function(event){
          let index = this.savedEvents.findIndex(e => e.id == event.id);
          if (index != -1) {
            this.savedEvents.splice(index, 1);
          } else {
            this.savedEvents.push(event);
          }
        },
        inArray: function(id) {
         return this.savedEvents.some(obj => obj.id == id);
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text]{
  padding: 5px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Events:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="event in events">
      <span class="btn" @click="toggleEvent(event)">
        {{ event.text }}
      </span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type your note here..." v-model="event.notes" v-if="inArray(event.id)">
    </li>
  </ol>
  <h2>
    Saved Events:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="event in savedEvents">
      <strong>{{ event.text }}</strong> {{ event.notes }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is nothing to do with reactivity.

When you add an event to `newEvents` by clicking the button it's using the same object that's in `events`. As there's only one object for each event everything work fine.

In the case of **Event 2** you're starting with two separate objects representing the same event, one in `events` and the other in `newEvents`. Changes to one will not change the other.

It's difficult to say what the appropriate solution is here without knowing your motivation for choosing these data structures but the example below ensures that both arrays contain the same object for **Event 2**.

The only thing I've changed from your original code is the `data` function.

```js
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data () {
        const data = {
          events: [
            { id: 1, text: "Event 1"},
            { id: 2, text: "Event 2", notes: 'Event Notes'},
            { id: 3, text: "Event 3"}
          ],
          newEvents: []
        }
        
        data.newEvents.push(data.events[1])
        
        return data
      },
      methods: {
       toggleEvent: function(event){
          let index = this.newEvents.findIndex(e => e.id == event.id);
          if (index != -1) {
            this.newEvents.splice(index, 1);
          } else {
            this.newEvents.push(event);
          }
        },
        inArray: function(id) {
         return this.newEvents.some(obj => obj.id == id);
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text]{
  padding: 5px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Events:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="event in events">
      <span class="btn" @click="toggleEvent(event)">
        {{ event.text }}
      </span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type your note here..." v-model="event.notes" v-if="inArray(event.id)">
    </li>
  </ol>
  <h2>
    New Events:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="event in newEvents">
      <strong>{{ event.text }}</strong> {{ event.notes }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There are various ways you could represent this data other than by using two lists of the same objects. You might use a boolean flag within the objects. Or you could use a separate object to hold the notes, keyed by event id. It's difficult to know what would work best for your scenario.

**Update:**

Based on the comments, you could do something like this to use the objects in `events` as canonical versions when loading `savedEvents`:

```js
loadSavedEvents () {
  // Grab events from the server
  someServerCall().then(savedEvents => {
    // Build a map so that the objects can be grabbed by id
    const eventMap = {}

    for (const event of this.events) {
      eventMap[event.id] = event
    }

    // Build the list of server events using the objects in events
    this.savedEvents = savedEvents.map(savedEvent => {
      const event = eventMap[savedEvent.id]
      this.$set(event, 'notes', savedEvent.notes)
      return event
    })
  })  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you mean about it not being the same object in the second array. I think what i need to do is loop over the first array and find any match by id that exists in the second array and then push the object found in the first array back into the second and set the notes property? Do you have a clean es6 way of doing that?

Comment: I've updated the array to be called savedEvents as this might help make more sense. This is all part of a much bigger UI, but basically the user can toggle to save the events they want from a predefined list. This is saved to the database, which is fine when they first create the entry, but the issue arises when they want to edit the entry and populate the events they initially added.

Comment: @Pedro I've updated my answer with an example of how you might do this without nested loops. However, unless the sizes of the two arrays are quite large you won't notice any significant performance gain from doing it this way.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as it is a bit cleaner than the nested loops

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$set` and `$delete` for avoiding reactivity lost

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#Vue-set

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Why? What do these two do? How do I use them? Please add some explanation to your answer and an example or two of how this helps OP. Perhaps even a link to the documentation where I can read about these two.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @skirtle the object from the list array needs to be pushed into the second array for it to be reactive. I have solved this by looping through and matching the id and then pushing this object into the second array. Not sure if this is the best / most efficient way to do this but it works now.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    eventsList: [
      { id: 1, text: "Event 1"},
      { id: 2, text: "Event 2"},
      { id: 3, text: "Event 3"}
    ],
    savedEvents: [
     { id: 2, text: "Event 2", notes: 'Event Notes'}
    ]
  },
  mounted() {
  this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
    let _temp = this.savedEvents;
      this.savedEvents = [];

      _temp.forEach(event => {
        this.eventsList.forEach(x => {
          if (event.id == x.id) {
            this.$set(x, "notes", event.notes);
            this.savedEvents.push(x);
          }
        });
      });
   },
   toggleEvent: function(event){
      let index = this.savedEvents.findIndex(e => e.id == event.id);
      if (index != -1) {
        this.savedEvents.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        this.savedEvents.push(event);
      }
    },
    inArray: function(id) {
     return this.savedEvents.some(obj => obj.id == id);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Events:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="event in eventsList">
      <span class="btn" @click="toggleEvent(event)">
        {{ event.text }}
      </span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type your note here..." v-model="event.notes" v-if="inArray(event.id)">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h2>
    Saved Events:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="event in savedEvents">
      <strong>{{ event.text }}</strong> {{ event.notes }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```